# Is there an algorithm like primary decomposition of an ideal that also assumes there are no zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, computational-algebra, primary-decomposition

I have a large system of polynomial equations and am trying to construct an irreducible decomposition of the corresponding variety.  It's large enough that feeding it to the standard radical/primary decomposition algorithm in Singular is computationally prohibitive.

However, many of the equations in the system factor.  If I introduce an additional assumption that there are no zero divisors, then a polynomial that factors (say $ab$) allows me to split the system into two systems, one containing $a=0$ and one containing $b=0$.  Knowing that $a=0$ in the first of these systems might produce additional factorization, and additional splitting.  This kind of pre-processing might produce a set of simpler systems that could then be fed to Singular, or a similar program, to complete the final decomposition.

Is anybody aware of such an algorithm?  Has it been published anywhere?